# mongodb to select some elements from within an array

Tags: mongodb

I store in mongodb some documents that have the following structure:

```
{
"a":1,
"b":24.212,
"uup":"X243",
"fvp": [
  {
    "feature_id": 10,
    "value": 180.157,
    "units": "A"
  },
  {
    "feature_id": 83,
    "value": 180.042252,
    "units": "mP",
  },
  {
    "feature_id": 62,
    "value": 0.234,
    "units": ""   
  }
]
}
```

and in general I may have some tens or even hundreds of elements inside array `fvp`. I want to perform a search as follows:

```
db.colX.find({"_id" : ObjectId("54b44b3bfeee5a13a43f34f0")});
```

but get just the elements in `fvp` whose `feature_id` is in a range of values. For example, I would like to get the following result:

{
    "a":1,
    "b":24.212,
    "uup":"X243",
    "fvp": [
      {
        "feature_id": 10,
        "value": 180.157,
        "units": "A"
      },
      {
        "feature_id": 62,
        "value": 0.234,
        "units": ""
      }
}

specifying that I want to get only the element of `fvp` with `"feature_id":10 OR "feature_id":62` . Is this anyhow possible? It seems that this can be done when just a single `feature_id` is specified, using the keyword `$elemMatch`. Here is an example:

```
db.colX.find(
  {"_id" : ObjectId("54b44b3bfeee5a13a43f34f0")},
  {
    feature_value_pairs: 
      {$elemMatch: {feature_id: 10} }
  }
);
```

**Question #1:** This suppresses other fields of my document from being displayed (e.g., `a`, `b`, `uup`). Can this be avoided?

Things get more complicated when I want to specify that I want the retrieved document to have the elements with feature_id equal to 10 and 83 together. Here is what I tried:

```
db.colX.find(
  {"_id" : ObjectId("54b44b3bfeee5a13a43f34f0")},
  {
    feature_value_pairs: 
     {$elemMatch: {feature_id: { $in: [10, 83]}} }
  }
);
```

However this displays just the element with `feature_id:10`.

**Question #2:** How can I achieve the desired result in mongodb?

Comment: @NeilLunn I updated my question. I read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3985214/retrieve-only-the-queried-element-in-an-object-array-in-mongodb-collection and it didn't help me find a solution to my problem.

Comment: `$elemMatch` in projection is just one of the possible answers. There are many answers on that question, so not just the accepted one is correct. For multiple matches use `.aggregate()` as explained in several answers there.